# No way to install or add libraries?

Tags: 8, acquia-cloud

I've been trying to set up a site on Acquia for a good 3 days now, and am baffled - Acquia doesn't allow Composer, the Acquia Dev Desktop does not sync libraries.  I've tried ludwig with no luck.

Is there any way to add csv/league libraries to Acquia? W/o this capability, I'm not sure how useful Acquia is, or am I missing something simple?

Comment: They have CI, but for a “normal” project you’ll need to add the libraries locally, and commit the vendor folder

Comment: You can't run these tools (Composer) in production, and you should not be running it in production. You need to build it locally, or in a free CI like GitLab CI, TravisCI or Circle CI, and deploy the result to Acquia. Acquia has Pipelines, but, I have not tried that service. Every project I have is commited to private repo in GitHub/GitLab, then a CI polls for changes and builds it, and deploys to Acquia or AWS. At a low level, you could commit the entire directory (vendor and all) to git, and push that up to Acquia if you don't want to deal with doing a build/deploy workflow.

Comment: I see this question _a lot_, I should write a post about it. It's not hard to do once you see it in action.

Comment: Look at BLT. It’s an Acquia command line program that allows you to work with Composer. It will build out your project from Composer.json as a read only artifact which it then deploys.

Comment: Following up here with an example of how to leverage GitLab for just this purpose: https://kevinquillen.com/deploying-drupal-8 - note: I host projects on Acquia, but I do not use Acquia Dev Desktop or BLT or other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Acquia has to have the full site, core, modules, themes, libraries, et.al. checked into their git repo in the format like:

```
git root
  docroot
    core
    modules
    themes
    etc.
    (includes index.php and other root files)
```

As Clive said, there is a pay for it CI process.  However, for the normal sites, you need to manage the site as a whole entity.  They do have Deployment hooks, but that is generally for clearing cache and the like.

FYI - I use composer on all my sites.  You run it locally and check in the composer files to the repo (e.g. the composer.lock, etc.).  Things like js libraries are added by manually adding repo's to the composer.json file if they are not composer friendly. E.g., here's how the jquery chosen plugin gets added:

```
"harvesthq.chosen": {
  "type" : "package",
  "package" : {
    "name" : "harvesthq/chosen",
    "version" : "1.8.7",
    "type" : "drupal-library",
    "dist" : {
      "url" : "https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases/download/v1.8.7/chosen_v1.8.7.zip",
      "type" : "zip"
    },
    "require" : {
      "composer/installers" : "^1.2.0"
    }
  }
},
```

It's also best to have the Drupal friendly paths defined in your composer file.  E.g.:

```
"extra" : {
    "installer-paths" : {
        "docroot/core" : [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "docroot/libraries/{$name}" : [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "docroot/modules/contrib/{$name}" : [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "docroot/themes/contrib/{$name}" : [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ]
```

These make sure things get placed properly by composer.

Answer (score -1):

Acquia dev desktop comes with composer and drush installed already.

You can also install composer on your machine by following the instructions here: https://getcomposer.org/download/

There is a good tutorial here to get you set up with a Drupal 8 site package built with composer here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhWAegz8glk

The github project for that Drupal 8 composer package is here: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project

You can then open a command window in devdesktop/Sites/your-new-d8-site/Web *(the root of the site you are building in dev)* and then run for example `composer require "drupal/commerce"`  This will pull in all the dependencies (and libraries) for Drupal Commerce 2 very easily without fussing with ludwig. it's very fast and easy.

Also here is a good video here on installing modules with composer:
https://modulesunraveled.com/drupal-8-composer-and-configuration-management/installing-and-uninstalling-modules-composer

Hope this helps!

Comment: The question is really about getting it on Acquia though. Or any host.

Comment: I guess I focused on the general question in the title. By building the site locally via composer or in dev desktop (which already has composer) you would have the libraries in your code base and could push it to their live environment. I agree with you that someone new to composer (like myself) should NOT be running it in a production environment.

Comment: I see your point though.  I just went through this so I know how frustrating it can be. I think I was just trying to help get it done. 

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still working on how to get Acquia Dev Desktop to sync the local site with the remote Acquia Cloud site; no matter what I do, I just can't figure out how to get everything up to the cloud.  I have the local site exactly the way I want it, but am only able togget little bits to upload.  I wish I could upload the whole site.

Comment: So were you able to get libraries locally then?

Comment: Yes, I can install libraries locally no problem.  The issue is I can't find a way to move or sync the site with the remote site on Acquia Cloud - the Dev Desktop function for this doesn't move any modules or libraries, only content, so it isn't useful - I'm still at a stand still.  I'm going to bail on Acquia; even with a paid subscription there isn't much tech support.  The tech team responds exactly 47.5 hours later with an email with a link to a document I've already read.  I'm getting the feeling it's for big projects with big budgets.  I'm going to set up my own server with composer.

Comment: Was my comment helpful in getting it set up on dev desktop? The original question implied there was difficulty even with dev desktop. Not sure my answer should have been down voted... Sorry to hear Acquia wasn't more helpful. These companies would do better for their reputation by being more helpful to people who are just getting started...